# Unable to find a field 'Product Code' for a sub-filter, under a Cross filter of Opportunities with product

Tags: reporting, product, cross-filter

I have this Report, of standard report type "Opportunities". I have added a cross filter "Opportunities with Products"
[image]
But I'm unable to find the standard field "Product Code" to be used in Sub-filter.
[image]
Is it a Salesforce limitation? I was unable to find any link/document from salesforce saying that. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of thought I got a work-around, which is an extremely easy one. I have created a formula field, which pulls the data of the Product code field. Being a custom field, you can show that field in the reports. Although it takes up an extra field, but at least, user will get what they want.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a [known limitation](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrnAAAS). The good thing though is that it's an idea 'Under Point Threshold' so you should vote for it so it gets included on the roadmap.

Unfortunately, there's no known workaround suggested either so you might need to pull the required data via custom Apex controllers.